# Differences between scipy and matlab spectogram

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm attempting to convert a MATLAB script to Python and running into slight differences between the results of the `spectrogram` function between MATLAB 2012a and Python using scipy v. 0.17.0.  In MATLAB I have the code:

```matlab
WINDOW = 240;
NOVERLAP = 180;
NFFT = 1024;
Fs = 4;

[~,F,T,PP] = spectrogram(data,hanning(WINDOW),NOVERLAP,NFFT,Fs);
```

where data is a one-dimensional array of about 15000 points, here PP will give the PSD for each section.

In Python the code looks something like this:

```py
from scipy.signal.spectral import spectrogram

WINDOW = 240
NOVERLAP = 180
NFFT = 1024
Fs = 4

[f, ts_i, pp] = spectrogram(data, fs=Fs, window='hanning', nperseg=WINDOW, 
                            noverlap=NOVERLAP, nfft=NFFT, detrend=False)
```

When I compare the output (MATLAB -- Python) I get similar but not identical results.  Below is an image of the first segment with the
Python and MATLAB results plotted along with the absolute difference
point by point.  This behavior is similar for other segments.  Again
the differences are not large but I'm curious about what is the ultimate 
cause of these differences?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scipy and MATLAB use different FFT libraries.  Scipy uses lapack, while MATLAB uses FFTW.  These libraries use different algorithms and produce slightly different results.

You can use FFTW with Python using the [pyFFTW](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyFFTW) package, and you can even monkey-patch scipy to [use FFTW](https://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/sphinx/tutorial.html#monkey-patching-3rd-party-libraries) under-the-hood for its FFT calculations, although even then it may not give numerically-identical results since the FFTW library may be called in different ways.